# if $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is connected then is $A´$ (derived set) connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

are the following statements true?

1) if $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is connected then is $A´$ connected?

2)if $A´$ is connected then is $A$ connected?

I can´t find any counterexamples. Can you help me please? I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: You should hopefully be able to find a counterexample for 2

Comment: {${1/n : n\in \mathbb N}$} is a counterexample for 2 :)

Comment: You need to find a non-connected $A$ such that $A'$ is connected. That example doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielRust are singletons not connected?

Comment: But $A´=${$0$} which is connected and the sequence is non connected

Comment: I was confusing the derived set with the closure, apologies.

Answer (score 2):

For (1), notice that if $A$ is connected and has at least two points then it cannot have isolated points. So $A' = A \bigcup A' = \overline{A}$ (closure of $A$). It is easy to see that any disconnection of $\overline{A}$ is a disconnection of $A$.

For (2), let $A$ be a any countable dense set.